# Combine 2 fonts to add missing characters

Tags: fonts

I love the [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) font, but it covers almost none of the Unicode characters I need.

Is it possible to merge it with another font that has lots of Unicode characters, producing a font with Inconsolata's letters, numbers, and basic symbols, but another font's obscure Unicode characters?

Would I need to find a font with the same character width to maintain fixed-widthness?

Comment: Why not just tell the type engine to backfill one font with the other?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use font forge to fix it yourself. [Font Forge (New Site)](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/downloads/windows/) here's the old site BTW:[FF Old Site](http://fontforge.github.io/editexample.html)